# Unable to click Save button for the first time when keyboard is opened in react-native-modal

Tags: react-native, button, touchableopacity, react-native-modal

In my react-native app.. it has a Modal imported from **react-native-modal**. Inside Modal there is a TextInput field. When I focus into textInput , keyboard is opened by default, but After entering the Text in TextInput when I try to click Save Button, am unable to click Save button. First it's closing keyboard then am able to click on Save button. Please can Anyone help on this issue?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPV9S.jpg)

Comment: Is TextInput is in the ScrollView ? Can you please post a related code ?

Comment: No, but I tried with ScrollView also.but I didn't work

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the `ScrollView` still try setting `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}` so that the save button captures taps and the `Keyboard` won't dismiss unless the `ScrollView` handles the tap.